# Netlogo: asking a turtle to count its neighbors

Tags: netlogo, neighbours

I´m asking a turtle to count its neighboring turtles that are healthy with the following code

```
let healthy-neighbors count turtles-on neighbors with [infected? = false]
```

I get the following: You can´t use INFECTED? in a patch context, because INFECTED? is turtle-only

My mistake must be basic, but can't find it, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetLogo is seeing that as `turtles-on (neighbors with [infected? = false)`, and since [`neighbors`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#neighbors) gives an agentset of patches, the `with` clauses is expecting patches, but patches do not have `infected?`, as it says in the error.

What you probably want is `let healthy-neighbors count (turtles-on neighbors) with [infected? = false]`.  The parentheses will tell NetLogo to get the turtles from the neighboring patches first, then filter them with `with`.