# Please Assist with Netlogo Model

Tags: simulation, netlogo, modeling

Please let me preface this with I am not a programmer by trade.  I am a social scientist using M&S for some research.  That being said, my goal is to use ABM (Netlogo) to create a model of state antifragility.  That is a model of states that get better under stress rather than deteriorate or are resilient (return to their pre-stress levels).

The idea for this model is simple.  Create agents (states) that have three properties-loops, capacity and performance. The Capacity of a state is defined as it's Agility + it's Learning + it's Power Conversion. (  I've done some regression analysis to see what the relationship between each of these variables and stress is and they are listed below. ) The state also has two loops-fragile and antifragile that are always running, but depending on the performance value and the stress value only one of those loops will activate to update the capacity/performance values to deal with the next stress.  Finally, a state's performance ties all those together.  That is, it is a function of capacity and stress.

States randomly roam about the world full of shocks (red patches with an intensity value). When the state comes across the patch, it interacts with that patch.  To interact, it activates a loop and then performs and update of its capacity and it's performance for the next stress. This happens until a state dies (it's too fragile and fails) or it becomes the maxium value of antifragile.

UPDATED CODE BELOW ( 22 July) JenB, I took your advice and stripped it down to it's basic parts by removing the looping functions.  Eventually, I'd like to get there in a future iteration, but for now I removed it.  The code below is my stripped down, updated version. Where I am stuck is the stop movement function.

Starting with the latter, I am still unsure how to set something true or false. I kept getting an error about a string not a value for that command. (Again, I am really, really a beginner at this and even reading the Netlogo Dictionary isn't that easy for me.)

Now that I think about it there is a third thing. I'd also like to randomize the value of the red patches ("shocks"). I believe the way I have it set up right now is that they all have the same value, but I'd like some to be bigger or smaller.

Thank all of you for all your help in this journey!

Please see the code below:

```
breed [states state]

states-own [learning powerconversion agility performance category]

patches-own [intensity]

;; TO SET UP ;;

to setup
  clear-all
  grow-shocks
  set-default-shape states "dot"
  create-states 10 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
    set size 2.5
    set performance random 100
    set learning random 10
    set powerconversion random 10
    set agility random 10
  
]
reset-ticks
end

;; TO GROWN SHOCKS ;;

to grow-shocks ;; to grow shocks in the international environment do the following:
 ask n-of number-shocks patches [
 set pcolor red ;; make them red
 set intensity random 10 ;; set their intensity to a random number between 0-10
  ]
end

;; TO GO ;;

to go
ask states [  ;; ask states to do the following : move, interact, update-category (AF, R, F)
  move
  interact
  update-category
  ]
tick
end

;; TO MOVE ;;

to move ;; to move do the following:
  right random 15
  left random 15
  forward 1
     if abs pxcor = max-pxcor
    [ set heading (- heading) ]
    if abs pycor = max-pxcor
    [ set heading (180 - heading) ]
end


;; TO INTERACT ;;

to interact ;; to interact with shocks do the following:
if pcolor = red [
    set pcolor black set intensity 0 ;; if the patch is red, turn the patch black and set intensity to 0
  update-performance ;; update-performance
  update-category
  ]
end


;; TO UPDATE PERFORMANCE ;;

to update-performance ;; to update a state's performance do the following:
  set performance (((-0.13 * learning ^ 3) + (1.89 * learning ^ 2) + (-5.72 * learning) + 8.13 ) +( 0.09 * agility ^ 3) + (1.29 * agility ^ 2) + (-3.45 * agility) + 5.57 +( 0.02 * powerconversion ^ 3) + (-0.89 * powerconversion ^ 2) + (9.93 * powerconversion) + -17.51 )
end


;; TO UPDATE STATE TYPE;;

to update-category ;; to update the state's type do the following:

  if performance > 75 [ ;; if the state has a performance value of over 75, turn it green indicating an antifragile state
   set color green
  ]
  if performance < 74 and performance > 35 [ ;; if the state has a performance value between 35 and 74, turn it yellow indicating a robust state
   set color yellow
  ]
  if performance < 34 and performance > 5 [ ;; if the state has a performance value between 1 and 34, turn it red indicating a failed state
    set color red
  ]
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is

Comment: updated code below

Answer (score 2):

So I am guessing the line throwing the too large error is this one:

```
to activate-antifragileloop
  set performance e ^ performance
end
```

This seems like a logic error to me. From the rest of your code, I am guessing performance numbers are generally in the range 0 to 100. Do you realise that e^100 = 2.6881171 x 10^43? It seems unlikely that you want performance to switch between numbers like 100 and numbers with 43 digits. I can't imagine a real world situation that you could be trying to represent where a key characteristic of the entities in the system has such a wildly varying value.

On the question of stopping, I would have another variable named something like `done?` that starts as `false` then you set it to `true` when you want it to stop. Then you can simply have `ask states with [not done?]` instead of `ask states` for any code that moves them around etc.

You said you are not a programmer. One of the best things a beginner can do is to make only minimal changes at a time. You have several problems with your code - this should almost never happen. Your life will be much easier if you only make one change at a time and get it working correctly before moving on. This is particularly important with NetLogo where it can be very difficult to work out whether something is working correctly because you are modelling systems that interact - how do you know whether the interaction is producing the results or a bug is producing the results?

Comment: Thank you for your help. For what it is worth, this one was built piece by piece with me checking to see if the code worked as intended which it has. I even wrote pseudo code. Is there anything else you can help me with to correct the problems I have? I really am trying to learn.  Thank you.

Comment: If it was built piece by piece, why are you simultaneously getting unrealistic changes in performance values and you can't make it stop? These are very different issues. I don't know what you did to check the code about performance - print some values, or calculate the mean and put that in a monitor, or use `inspect` to watch the value for some turtles. Any of these would have alerted you to the fact that the numbers vary wildly and suggested that you need to reconsider what you are trying to represent with your performance variable.

Comment: The other problem I spotted just reading through is the line `report sum [ "green" ]` - this doesn't make sense. You can use StackOverflow to help you improve, but you need to get used to asking a specific question. You show just the relevant bit of code and explain what is wrong, for example this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62582411/netlogo-asking-a-turtle-to-count-its-neighbors/62582901#62582901.

Comment: For more general learning, NetLogo programming is a skill - which means you learn it by practice. It's hard to judge what would help you - I haven't seen beginners use `to-report` before, so I suspect you've already done some tutorials. But tutorials, the NetLogo programming guide, and a NetLogo book are probably your next steps. Recommendations are off topic on SO, but the NetLogo site has some resources links. Have a look at all of them to decide what is most suitable for you.

Comment: I did strip down the code a bit and took out the loops that didnt have the sound logic.  The code runs now, and I updated it with some new questions based on the scaling back.

Comment: Please ask a new question rather than edit your existing one. The goal of SO is to have a set of specific questions with specific answers so that other coders with similar problems can find an answer without asking a question. Editing both hides the previous question and puts multiple different ideas into the same Q&A, to say nothing of ending up with long back and forth comments.